# Visual Studio 2012 - How to assign multiple build actions to a TypeScript file

Tags: visual-studio, typescript, embedded-resource, buildaction

I am using Visual Studio 2012 to create a class library project that will also include a number of TypeScript (`.ts`) files, as well as their generated `.js` and `.js.map` files. All of these files need to be included in the assembly as embedded resources, so that they can be exposed to a consuming ASP.NET MVC application via a custom `VirtualPathProvider`.

Note: although only the generated JavaScript files are essential for the production environment, the `.ts` and `.js.map` files must also be accessible to the web application, for debugging.

This presents a conflict, since TypeScript files are usually assigned the `TypeScriptCompile` build action but I also need them to be assigned `EmbeddedResource`.

Is there any way to assign multiple build actions to a VisualStudio project component? Alternatively, is there another way to get TypeScript to compile files that are not explicitly marked as `TypeScriptCompile` or to get Visual Studio to embed files that are not marked as `EmbeddedResource`?

Thanks for your suggestions,

Tim

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you had a TypeScript file that referenced all of the others, only it would need to have the `TypeScriptCompile` type as the compiler *should* walk all the dependencies and compile all the rest too.

So creating a file that acts as the compilation target and that references all of your other files might allow you to change all the rest to `EmbeddedResource`.

Comment: That's a great suggestion - thanks. I'll try it and post the results here.

Comment: Yes, Steve, that was an ingeniously easy-to-implement solution and it works perfectly. Thanks again.